# How to change a local user to LDAP

Tags: sonarqube

We have a local user account in SonarQube 5.6 that was created before we added the LDAP plugin.

How can we change that account to use LDAP rather than the local account password for authentication?

It doesn't seem like a simple matter of deleting the account and logging in again, since AFAIK user accounts can't be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

You need to first delete the user then log in with its login.

It's true when you delete a user some data remains in database, but in any case you can safely use its login with another identity provider, LDAP in your case.

Comment: Do you mean "deactivating" by "deleting"? (I'm just asking to clarify the confusion in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842874/how-to-migrate-a-technical-user-to-a-ldap-one )

Comment: @slartidan There's no difference between deactivating and deleting => Only one action is available in SonarQube,

Comment: Deactivate + login with AD credentials worked for me using SonarQube 7.9.1

Answer (score 0):

As the official answer doesn't work, here's what I did that worked in a similar case (see [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842874/how-to-migrate-a-technical-user-to-a-ldap-one/)):

Changing field user_local in table users from 0 to 1 did the trick. I can't imagine this being recommended by SonarQube, but as of now (8 months after the change), I did not find any side effects.